# Running a program from command prompt and using argv in C++

Tags: c++, command-line

I have written a program that takes the filename from argv[1] and do operations on it .
When debugging from visual studio I pass the filename from project options>>debugging>>command arguments and It works fine and prints all results correctly .

But when trying from the command prompt , I go to the dir of project/debug the I type

```
program
```

It works fine and prints **"No valid input file"** in the same window (Which is my error handling technique)

but when i type

```
program test.txt
```

It just does nothing . I think no problem in code because it works fine from the debugger .

Code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
 { 
int nLines;
string str;

if(argv[1]==NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Not valid input file" << endl;
    return 0 ;

}
ifstream infile(argv[1]);

getline(infile,str);
nLines = atoi(str.c_str());//get number of lines

for(int line=0 ;line < nLines;line++)
{
    //int currTime , and a lot of variables ..
            //do a lot of stuff and while loops
          cout << currTime <<endl ;

}
    return 0 ;
    }
```

Comment: There's not enough here to go by. Obviously there *is* a problem with the code, or it would work, right?

Comment: I posted the code , though visual studio debugger prints the results fine .

Comment: I am inside the right directory , It printed "No valid input file"

Comment: _if(argv[1]==NULL)_ should be replaced with _if (argc != 2)_, add _if/while (infile)_ before each IO operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't check if file was successfully opened, whether getline returned error code or not, or if string to integer conversion didn't fail. If any of those error occur, which I guess is the case, `nLines` will be equal to `0`, no cycles will be performed and program will exit with return code `0`.

Comment: Well , I found the mistake which was that the test file in the project directory not the current directory so It worked for the debugger . So your answer is the most useful . I needed to check if file opened successfully or no .

Answer (score 3):

This code worked correctly for me running on the command line.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    int nLines;
    string str;

    if(argv[1]==NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Not valid input file" << endl;
        return 0 ;

    }
    else
        std::cout << "Input file = " << argv[1] << endl;
}
```

Output :

```
C:\Users\john.dibling\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\hacks_vc9\x64\Debug>hacks_vc9.exe hello
Input file = hello
```

By the way, this code is dangerous, at best:

```
if(argv[1]==NULL)
```

You should probably be checking the value of `argc` before attempting to dereference a possibly-wild pointer.

Comment: Thanks for this note about argv.

Answer (score 1):

The file probably contains an invalid numeric first line (perhaps starting with a space or the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)).

That would explain no output, since if `nLines == 0` no output should be expected